# Machine learning to classify tweets into topics – Where to start?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to build something that can classify tweets (from my timeline or lists) by topic. I can of course provide a dataset of tweets pre-classified for each variant, but then the software should be able to learn from that and apply that logic to new, future tweets.

Variant A) Take all tweets of a timeline and decide if one was "relevant" or "irrelevant".

Variant B) Decide which of x topics a tweet belongs to.

Variant C) Group similar tweets together that are related.

So now my questions:

- Where to start?
- What are the correct terms to Google?
- What libraries or software should I look at?

(I am most comfortable with JS and PHP, but of course this is only semi relevant.)

---

(I [asked this before on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346207/machine-learning-to-classify-tweets-into-topics-where-to-start), but of course got "OFFTOPIC!!1" in the comments, where luckily someone posted a link to CrossValidated - and here I am.)

Comment: And _please_ let me know if I should change anything in my question to be a better fit to this community.

Comment: You might read up on the difference between methods of classification and of clustering.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](https://github.com/keon/awesome-nlp) of resources for Natural Language Processing (NLP), in there you will find tutorials, libraries and articles that should help you get a better grasp on the topic and solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Until now I mostly got "classification" and "categorization" as responses on other platforms. Is "NLP" a) a competely different thing, b) related, or c) the same thing?

Comment: machine learning and classification are a big part of NLP but there specific details particular only to NLP